# Date between MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a field of type date within a MySQL database. My user places a date into a field (format dd-mm-yyyy) which I convert into yyyy-mm-dd for insertion into the database. This works fine. I can see the date in there as (for example) 2012-04-04.

My issue is that I then select this record, convert the date to the format I wish to display (dd-mm-yyyy) and get 03-04-2012. I understand why, in that my database is set to UTC, however the user is on Berlin time, therefore 04-04-2012 00:00 in Berlin is 03-04-2012 23:00 UTC.

The issue means that if I then save the displayed date (03-04-2012), the next time I see it, it displays as 02-04-2012 because I saved only the date and therefore the system is assuming a 00:00 time again.

I cannot see a way around this other than setting this as a datetime type rather than a date type, however I would rather not do that as time (for various reasons) is stored in a separate field. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you select and convert it?

Comment: My select statement does not seek to modify the date. I use date('d-m-Y',$startdate) for the display.

Comment: Even if you don't actually display the time portion, could you use it when you generate your date? That way when you format it for the user the date should be correct.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the end result. Just wanting to know if there is a simple solution that I do not know about. I never assume I know all the answers, however I usually find stackoverflow does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inserting a record you add as datetime current UTC time, after that every user in their profile may want to/or set his timezone.

If you know the timezone of the user u can easy convert the datetime to user locale time. Because you know the differences in hours/minutes between the time.

P.S. You can store the datetime as varchar and save the unix timestamp in this field. Unix timestamp is based on current timezone I think.

UPDATE:
I think that might help

```
$date = time();
dump(date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date)); // 03-04-2012 08:43:38

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
dump('London: '. date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date)); // London: 03-04-2012 11:43:38

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
dump('Berlin: '. date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date)); // Berlin: 03-04-2012 12:43:38

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
dump('Sofia: '. date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date)); // Sofia: 03-04-2012 13:43:38
```

dump function returns `'<pre>'. $something .'</pre>'`;

Comment: That is correct, however the issue is that the data has a timezone independent of the user. It is not a blanket 'show all timestamps as NY time because that is where I am' but rather this record is NY, this one is Berlin, this one is London etc. and therefore show the time in those timezones. However, I think there is no choice but to convert to and from UTC on a record by record basis....

Comment: I appreciate the extra notes. As sometimes I am showing 200 results, constantly changing the default timezone seems over the top. I have found a small tutorial on how to do a case by case conversion without messing with the default settings. That was I will leave default as the users location, and mess with the displayed time parameters on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

UTC is the international time standard. It is similar to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), except that UTC observes no daylight saving time (DST) and is based on a 24-hour clock. Zero (0) hours UTC is midnight GMT. The local 24-hour time convention is converted to UTC by adding or subtracting hours based on location in relation to the prime meridian, as well as local daylight saving time considerations.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure both time zones are same. Then, don't store in `datatime` format, use integer. Convert the date to timestamps and then store. Like

```
$time = time(); //get the current time stamp
//Now insert $time
```

Now, both places are in common ground, You may do as you like. Changing date among different timezone is rather easy.

```
echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", $time);
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work except I need to be able to go across timezones, so have to support UTC for simplicity....

Comment: @ChrisHardaker, You have no idea how easy this is. See my update

Comment: Sorry, however you are correct in that I only see problems with this. From what I see with your solution, I remove all awareness of other time zones. I do want to show things to New York in their Berlin time, however I do not want to show things in New York that have passed in Berlin. I think with your example, I will see in New York at 9am, something that is planned for Berlin at 10am, however in Berlin it is 5pm and therefore that event has passed. The end result is that using the 'date' data type was a poor design decision on my part, so I pay the price now...